# Restart unfiltered server on keypress

Tags: sbt, unfiltered

I often run a dispatcher server in `sbt ~run`.

```
  unfiltered.netty.Http(port)
    .handler(plan)
    .run()

  Http.shutdown()
```

When I start up my server, it says:

> Embedded server running on port 8080. Press any key to stop.

However, only ENTER will stop the server.  Unfortunately, ENTER also stops `sbt`.  How can I set up unfiltered so that it actually stops on any key within `sbt`?  I would like pressing a key to stop the server and cause `sbt` to re-compile and re-run the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can do continuous hot reloading using [sbt-revolver](https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver) and JRebel. There's a [free license](https://my.jrebel.com/plans/) of JRebel for Scala users.

1. Start sbt shell.
2. `reStart` starts a forked JVM that's exit trapped.
3. If you installed JRebel correctly, compiled classes from `~products` would get loaded into the forked JVM.

See [Hot Reloading](https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver#hot-reloading).